# Cannot using movie2avi in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, avi, movie

I am trying to use the movie2avi function in MATLAB. I simply copy the sample program in my MATLAB R2015a:

```
nFrames = 20;

% Preallocate movie structure.
mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata', [],...
                        'colormap', []);

% Create movie.
Z = peaks; surf(Z); 
axis tight manual
set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
for k = 1:nFrames 
   surf(sin(2*pi*k/20)*Z,Z)
   mov(k) = getframe(gcf);
end

% Create AVI file.
movie2avi(mov, 'myPeaks.avi', 'compression', 'None');
```

But an error message appears:

> Error using avi Unexpected Error. Reason: Failed to open file.
>
> Error in audiovideo.internal.aviwriter (line 168)
>                 aviobj.FileHandle = avi('open',filename);
>
> Error in movie2avi (line 63) avimov =
>   audiovideo.internal.aviwriter(filename,varargin{:});
>
> Error in MakeMovie (line 36) movie2avi(mov, 'myPeaks.avi',
>   'compression', 'None');

What's wrong here? Please help.

Comment: do you have write permision in the fodler you work on? I copy pasted that code and works very goo din my computer

Comment: I think yes, I am the administrator.

Comment: Make sure you do. That code works, really. try working in another folder.

Comment: Use  `FFmpeg` instead.  Much easier, and it's a tool meant to do this stuff.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft so FFmpeg converts Matlab framedata to avi? I doubt. Your comment seems Spammy

Comment: @AnderBiguri  I'm suggesting that the file be exported in some format that  FFmpeg can read, and create the avi that way.  Remember that "avi" is not a format: it's a container.  How you build a movie depends on the codecs selected.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft but its not a file. Its 3D matrices describing data. in Matlab, movie2avi is the way to go, adn gives very good quality results.

Comment: That could should work.  I just tried it on random data.  Try writing to a folder that you actually have legitimate permissions on.

Comment: Actually, the [`VideoWriter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-object.html) class is the way to go. As the documentation states, `movie2avi` is deprecated.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have myPeaks.avi open somewhere else.

Comment: @Ander Biguri Thanks for comment. Actually I don't know how to check for permission in the folder. I always think that my account is the administrator account and only me would use this computer.

Comment: I have typed the command " fileattrib . " and it shows: Name: 'C:\Users\SupUsr\Desktop\Postdoctoral Research\DDFD\Practice' archive: 0 system: 0 hidden: 0 directory: 1 UserRead: 1 UserWrite: 1 UserExecute: 1 GroupRead: NaN GroupWrite: NaN GroupExecute: NaN OtherRead: NaN OtherWrite: NaN OtherExecute: NaN It means that I can read and write in this directory. So what cause the error?

Comment: Update: I added a command "set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer');" when I use R2014a and the problem is solved. It is just like using writeVideo in R2015a without that command. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problem,Just delete history of previous Object before use movie2avi to create new movie,And My Problem
Solved.In your code:

```
    nFrames = 20;

    % Preallocate movie structure.
    mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata', [],...
                    'colormap', []);

    % Create movie.
    Z = peaks; surf(Z); 
    axis tight manual
    set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
    for k = 1:nFrames 
    surf(sin(2*pi*k/20)*Z,Z)
    mov(k) = getframe(gcf);
    end

    if(isobject(aviobj))
    clear mov % if mov exist
    end

   % Create AVI file.
   movie2avi(mov, 'myPeaks.avi', 'compression', 'None');

    clear mov
```